# How to count the digits in a number, including leading zeros?

Tags: c, scanf

This code tries to count digits in the input number.

If the input number is `06584`, the output of this code will be `4`, excluding zero. How can I get `5` as output (so counting the zero)?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int n,c=0,d;
    printf("Enter no\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n!=0)
    {
        d=n%10;
        c++;
        n=n/10;
    }
    printf("No of digits=>%d\n",c);
}
```

Comment: No mathematical solution is going to detect a leading zero. You'd have to read the user's input as a string and get the string length.

Comment: you should add `printf` of n before your while , you will see that the leading 0(s) has gone

Comment: `char n[100]; scanf("%s",n); c=strlen(n);`. That will give you the number of digits assuming the input is valid. To verify that it is indeed a number use `strtol`.

Comment: Use `%n` [sample code](http://ideone.com/p7OV1H)

Comment: For negative input like `"-123"`, should that report 3 or 4?

Answer (score 3):

> How to count the digits in a number, including leading zeros?

To count the number of digits entered, including leading 0 digits, record the scan offsets before and after the number.  This method reports a sign character as a digit, but does not count leading white-space.

Use `"%n"` to record the number of characters scanned so far. [@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542814/how-to-count-the-digits-in-a-number-including-leading-zeros/42543369#comment72221999_42542814)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
  int begin;
  int after = 0;
  int number;
  printf("Enter number\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  //     +--- consumes leading white-space
  //     | +- record number of characters scanned
  scanf(" %n%d%n", &begin, &number, &after);
  if (after > 0) {
    printf("No of digits: %d\n", after - begin);
    printf("Value read  : %d\n", number);
  } else {
    puts("Invalid input");
  }
}
```

Output

```
Enter number
  000123
No of digits: 6
Value read  : 123
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char n[101];
    printf("Enter no\n");
    scanf("%100s",n);
    printf("No of digits=>%d\n",strlen(n));
}
```